# Qt Creator - SFML Link to a console project

Tags: c++, macos, qt, console, qt-creator

I am currently working on a project in console mode in which I wish to implement a sound. Our choice then turned to SFML, we get to install and use on OS X. However, we need to make it compatible with Qt project for rendering, I generate a.Profile and integrate our code and the library.

In OS X, no problem, installation and use possible. However, for this project, we need to integrate it into the code to make only archive. But every attempt to link our project with the aforementioned library, we run into errors.

Could you tell us exactly what files are to be included in the project? Working on protecting machines, we cannot install packages. Here is the screen of the integration window, the button exhilarating. We cannot select the Library.

[image: ScreenShoot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to use the external library instead of the internal.